# Trying to replace NAs with column means in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run this simple code over data which is a data frame of 800 features and 200000 observations.

This simple code that I always used:

```
C <- ncol(data)
for (i in 1:C){
  print(i)
  data[is.na(data[,i]),i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm=T) 
}
```

returns:

```
[1] 1    
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.6 Mb
```

I don't really understand why because I can independently call for the mean of the feature without any errors. Any

Answer (score 0):

That error means you are running out of memory to compute the means.

Sometime, based on the number of references to an object, R will copy the object, make the change to the copy and then replace the original ([reference](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification-in-place)).  That is likely what is happening in your case.

I recommend you use the **data.table** package which allows copy-less variable modification.